# How to create new Vue instance inside Nuxt3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

in Vue 2, I was able to create a new Vue instance with

```js
<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
export default {
mounted() { const instance = new Vue({}) } 
}
</script>
```

Now, if try this with nuxt3, it throw an error :

*This expression is not constructable.
Type 'typeof import(".../node_modules/vue/dist/vue")' has no construct signatures.*

So I replace

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
```

by

```js
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.cjs.js'
```

But when I create my new Vue instance, I have a warning inside my browser console telling me that there is an error : **during execution of mounted hook**

Any idea to solve my issue ?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want a new instance?

Comment: I want create a new component which is encapscule into shadow dom

Comment: For other people who have the same question, but for example because they need an EventBus:
https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/2288